MacOS ARM chip virtqemud-sock missing
I am trying to run an x86 VM on Mac Silicon using QEMU, Libvirt and Vagrant.
I have installed QEMU via brew as well as libvirt:
brew install libvirt qemu
When I attempt to launch the VM via vagrant I get the following error:
Error while connecting to Libvirt: Error making a connection to libvirt URI qemu:///system:
Call to virConnectOpen failed: Failed to connect socket to '/opt/homebrew/var/run/libvirt/virtqemud-sock': No such file or directory

I checked the libvirt service is running as expected:
brew services list
Name    Status  User     File
libvirt started xxxx ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.libvirt.plist
unbound none

Where other people have had the same issue on different OS's the resolution is to start the libvirtd service via systemctl which isn't an option with the brew/mac installation.
I have also attempted to add mode = "legacy" to both /opt/homebrew/etc/libvirt/libvirtd.conf and /opt/homebrew/etc/libvirt/libvirt.conf as per the following documentation: https://libvirt.org/uri.html#mode-parameter. For sanity I have also tried the direct option. I do question if the config change is being picked up.
Here is my Vagrant file, although looking at other peoples similar issues on different arch/OS's Vagrant isn't the issue here:
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
    config.vm.box = "mybox"
    config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", type: "rsync"
    config.vm.box_download_insecure = true
    config.vm.provider "libvirt" do |libvirt|
        libvirt.driver = "qemu"
        libvirt.emulator_path = "/opt/homebrew/bin/qemu-system-x86_64"
        libvirt.uri = "qemu:///system"
        libvirt.memory = 2048
        libvirt.cpus = 2
    end
end

I'd be very grateful if anyone running a Mac arm chip has successfully achieved the above and could shed some light on what I am doing wrong here. Thank you.
